# How to show date correctly in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I am building a web portal with solidity contract integration. In the contract, I have saved the date in `uint` from like this `1539491531`.

When I show it on the web page it looks like this:

[image: view]

It showing different dates. But when I do like this in the code.

```
<Feed.Date>{Date(date)}</Feed.Date>
```

All dates are shown as the time right now like this: `Mon Oct 15 2018 08:44:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

How can I solve this problem?. Can someone help me to solve this problem?. Thank you.

Comment: Don't post images, post text. Not everyone can see images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the new before Date(date)
Also, maybe try multiplying that value by 100

```
<Feed.Date>{new Date(date*100)}</Feed.Date>
```

Comment: The *100 is to make up for the seconds in case the timestamp is not complete. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: it looks like those timestamps, so you'll need to multiply by *1000* to make it milliseconds - UTC timestamps are traditionally in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're missing the `new` keyword.

```
Date() // Mon Oct 15 2018 13:30:55 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
Date(1) // Mon Oct 15 2018 13:30:55 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
Date('something random') // Mon Oct 15 2018 13:30:55 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

However, with `new`:

```
new Date() // Mon Oct 15 2018 13:30:55 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
new Date(1) // Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
new Date('something random') // Invalid Date
```

See the [note on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object

When you call `Date()` without `new`, it calls a function that returns a string of the current time. It takes no arguments, but in Javascript, you can pass whatever you like to it and it will still work, so it just ignores any arguments that you pass, and returns a **`string`**, and not a Date of the current time.

```
typeof Date() // string
typeof new Date() // object
```

As noted by [edvilme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52809431/4625697), your timestamps also look to be in **seconds**, not milliseconds as required by `new Date()` - you can just multiply by 1000 to make it work

```
new Date(1529491531) // Mon Jan 19 1970 02:51:31 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
new Date(1529491531 * 1000) // Wed Jun 20 2018 20:45:31 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting your code like so:

```
<Feed.Date>{ new Date(date) }</Feed.Date>
```

By creating a date object (via `new`), you can simplify conversion from UTC epoch time (ie the value of `date`) into a human readable date string.

For more information on Date, [see this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the format function to help you with this.

```js
Date.prototype.format = function(format)
{
 var o = {
 "M+" : this.getMonth()+1, //month
 "d+" : this.getDate(),    //day
 "h+" : this.getHours(),   //hour
 "m+" : this.getMinutes(), //minute
 "s+" : this.getSeconds(), //second
 "q+" : Math.floor((this.getMonth()+3)/3),  //quarter
 "S" : this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond
 }
 if(/(y+)/.test(format)) format=format.replace(RegExp.$1,
 (this.getFullYear()+"").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
 for(var k in o)if(new RegExp("("+ k +")").test(format))
 format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
 RegExp.$1.length==1 ? o[k] :
 ("00"+ o[k]).substr((""+ o[k]).length));
 return format;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
var d1 = new Date();
d1.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
```